# Vulkan isn't able to access the Intel GPU but OpenCL is on WSL2

Tags: windows, gpu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vulkan

I wanted to learn Vulkan and since I'm on Windows I use the Windows subsystem Linux (WSL) for everything I program. The only problem I have is that VUlkan is somehow unable to access the GPU. I have an Intel iRIS x. I've tried many things. After I installed all the OpenCL tools and headers I tested opencl and opencl was able to find the graphics card on WSL2 but Vulkan always uses llvmpipe which makes no sense in my opinion.

1. Verifying WSL version (On Windows):

```
> wsl -v
WSL version: 2.0.14.0
Kernel version: 5.15.133.1-1
```

2. Trying with OpenCL (On WSL):

```
$ clinfo | grep -A 1 "Device Type"
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
--
  Device Type                                     CPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
```

3. I reinstalled the Vulkan binaries, tools, and headers.
4. I reinstalled the Intel GPU driver on Windows even though I already had the newest version.
5. I installed all updates and even upgraded to Windows 11.
6. I restarted my PC multiple times, for example, after driver installation.
7. I ran the vkCube example and only got llvmpipe (WSL):

```
$ vkcube
Selected GPU 0: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits), type: CPU
```

8. I ran vulkaninfo and only got llvmpipe (WSL).

On Windows, Vulkan and Intel GPU work fine without any problems:

```
GPU id : 0 (Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics):
```

Nothing worked, and I don't know what to do. OpenCL works, but Vulkan just won't work.
Please help